# Xubuntu Title Bar Missing

Tags: xubuntu, titlebar

I am using Xfce4.10 on Ubuntu 12.04. When I installed Xubuntu-desktop and logged into Xubuntu session. The title bars were missing with only the minimize,maximize and close buttons visible. Can someone help on solving this problem....!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are posting on google docs, but folks are going to need to request permission to see it. Can you post this on pastebin or imgur so we might link this inline to your question?

Comment: Changed the permission settings....I hope you can see it now.

Comment: Thanks. You can delete your comment. Can you run the command `xfwm4 --replace` from a terminal and see if that fixes your issue? You may need to enter Ctrl-C afterwards.

Comment: Not working. the screen just blinked and nothing happened.

Comment: Gives Error       xfce4-panel: Unknown option --replace.
Type "xfce4-panel --help" for usage.

Comment: Sorry. `xfce4-panel -r`

Comment: Yeah this time the upper and lower panels just blinked..

Comment: Lame. My last suggestions would be to `rm ~/.Xauthority` file and `rm ~/.gtkrc-2.0` file, if you have them. Then log out and log back in. After that, I am stumped. Sorry.

Comment: rm ~/.gtkrc-2.0 don't have this file.

Comment: Forget about about it. I'm just gonna remove xfce 4.10 and install the official 4.8 for ubuntu 12.04. Thankx For the Help....

Comment: Stupid me. It was just a theme problem....   :)

Comment: No. That's great that you fixed the issue. AND came back to let us know. Feel free to post and accept that as the accepted answer. Maybe add some details on how you figturged it out + fixed it would be great. Thanks,

Comment: I am not really ubuntu savvy but all I did was set up SYNC IN THE BROWSER
and it worked perfectly,menu bar back with no messing.
AL

Comment: I actually found @KevinBowen was right about replacing the window manager. Changing the theme on its own did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay...So the problem wasn't in XFCE.

It was in the default Xubuntu theme "GREYBIRD". To fix this, simply go to: Settings Manager -> Window manager and change the theme to anything other than greybird or greybird_compact.   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxV5lO2quUeqdGV5VktublJlVm8/edit?usp=sharing

My XFCE is now FIXED!

Comment: I had the same problem after installing the [Quantal LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) on Xubuntu 12.04 in a VirtualBox 4.2.12 virtual machine. (Surprisingly, I had no issue on Xubuntu 12.04 on a real machine). Changing the theme did not work for me. I solved logging into the Xfce session, then logging into the Xubuntu session.

Answer (score 2):

I think changing the theme would fix this. Try greybird or bluebird. They are really good.
To do this, open settings manager which is accessible from the app menu, or the right click menu.
Further navigate to windows manager, there you'll see a list of themes. Most of these should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

With Xubuntu 22.04 I had title bars missing, along with other wierd things happening.

The way I was able to fix it was by running:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions/*
```